# Uninitialized constant error in Rails with new test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Why am I getting this error?
https://gist.github.com/770219

Comment: What's in `legal_documents_controller.rb:12`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/770240

Comment: is there a LegalDocument model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LegalDocument` model may be defined in a filename that is not correct. The file must be located in *any* subdirectory of `app` and be called `legal_document.rb`. The name is really important, as this is how Rails does autoloading.